# Little freeze at the very start of plane animation

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

Have following code which works pretty as expected besides a little freeze just before first airplane animation begins. And my code is:

```
enum TurnDirection: String {
    case left
    case right
    case none
}

extension GameScene {


    fileprivate func turnPlayerPlane(direction: TurnDirection) {
        let forwardAction = SKAction.animate(with: textureArray.reversed(), timePerFrame: 0.05, resize: true, restore: false)
        player.run(forwardAction) { [unowned self] in
                self.stillTurning = false
        }
    }
}

class GameScene: SKScene {

    let textureArray = [SKTexture(imageNamed: "01"),
                        SKTexture(imageNamed: "02")]

    let motionManager = CMMotionManager()
    var xAcceleration: CGFloat = 0
    var player: SKSpriteNode!
    var stillTurning = false

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

        performPlaneFly()
    }

    fileprivate func performPlaneFly() {
        let planeWaitAction = SKAction.wait(forDuration: 1)
        let planeDirectionAction = SKAction.run {
            self.playerDirectionCheck()
        }

        let planeSequence = SKAction.sequence([planeWaitAction, planeDirectionAction])
        let planeSequenceForever = SKAction.repeatForever(planeSequence)
        player.run(planeSequenceForever)
    }

    fileprivate func playerDirectionCheck() {
            turnPlayerPlane(direction: .right)
    }
```

I commented out different parts of the code and it is seems to be **turnPlayerPlane** function but really do not understand what is going on there so heavy to perform before first animation begins.

Can someone explain what I did wrong there?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having sit like for 10 hours with this freezes at the beginning I've found solution. And as usual solution is not as difficult as it seemed to be. So freezes came up because of performance drop because of first render of all textures. After textures are rendered as I said freezes are gone.

So after I rewrote a bit my code I've made separate file private method which I call first in **didMove:to view** to render all textures before their use.:

```
   fileprivate func planeAnimationFillArrays() {

        SKTextureAtlas.preloadTextureAtlases([SKTextureAtlas(named: "PlayerPlane")]) { [unowned self] in
            self.leftTextureArrayAnimation = {
                var array = [SKTexture]()
                for i in stride(from: 10, through: 1, by: -1) {
                    let number = String(format: "%02d", i)
                    let texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "\(number)")
                    array.append(texture)
                }
                SKTexture.preload(array, withCompletionHandler: { 
                    print("preload is done")
                })
                return array
            }()

            self.rightTextureArrayAnimation = {
                var array = [SKTexture]()
                for i in stride(from: 10, through: 20, by: 1) {
                    let number = String(format: "%02d", i)
                    let texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "\(number)")

                    array.append(texture)
                }
                SKTexture.preload(array, withCompletionHandler: {
                    print("preload is done")
                })
                return array
            }()
        }
    }
```

Before all I used method that rendered my spriteAtlas **SKTextureAtlas.preloadTextureAtlases([SKTextureAtlas(named: "XXX")])** and in completion handler of this method I used **SKTexture.preload([SKTextures], completionHandler)** before each animation array return. After all this little freezes are completely gone.

Now this code has some duplication but it seems to me it is easier to understand what it is done here. Hope someone found this solution helpful.

You know how to reduce this code please fill free to edit or post your own solution.

Thank you!